# Fetch Drupal nodes as json by url/title

Tags: 7, services

Our Drupal system has the Services module enabled and is able to return nodes as json using the following url format

http://www.example.com/my_endpoint_path/node/123.json

But I want to retrieve a node using the URL alias I set in the URL path settings tab. I hoped the following would work

http://www.example.com/my_endpoint_path/my_pages_URL_alias.json

But it does not. Is there a way to configure Drupal/Services to fetch nodes by that URL rather than the node id?

Answer (score 2):

In Service Module API, Some hooks are presents to help you.
You need to alter or add your own implementation of this service.

The second link is a file where you have the default service implementation.
You can try to alter this configuration with your own by using "hook_services_resources_alter".

I can't test but you can try and custom this snippet :

```
function YOUR_MODULE_services_resources_alter(&$resources, &$endpoint) {
    $['node']['operations']['retrieve']['callback'] = '_your_retreive_method';
    $['node']['operations']['retrieve']['args']     = array(
        'name' => 'node_alias',
        'optional' => FALSE,
        'source' => array('path' => 0), // Put your path index here
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'The alias node to get',
    );
}

function _your_retreive_method($node_alias){
    // transform your alias to nid
    $path   = drupal_get_normal_path($node_alias);    
    if($path !== $node_alias && ctype_digit($nid = str_replace('node/','',$path))){
        return _node_resource_retrieve($nid);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Links :

- [Service API Docs](https://drupal.org/node/783724)
- [File with an implementation of a service](http://drupalcode.org/project/services.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/docs/services.services.api.php)

Comment: Thanks - this helped get me started. Unfortunately it doesn't work with multi-part aliases, which is a pretty serious limitation. (*my-alias* will work but not *about-us/my-alias*.) I've remedied this by converting the slashes on the client end and then reverting them in my callback function. I would rather send the alias as a parameter in a query, but couldn't implement it successfully.

Comment: Here's a gist that handles multi-part aliases, provided the slashes are converted in the request: https://gist.github.com/laradevitt/6ab86bf7ebbd3215b20b

Answer (score 0):

Payou's answer worked for me with some additions. In the `YOUR_MODULE_services_resources_alter` function I also needed to specify a custom access function:

```
  $resources['node']['operations']['retrieve']['access callback'] = '_YOUR_MODULE_node_resource_access';
  $resources['node']['operations']['retrieve']['access arguments append'] = TRUE;
```

And add the access function:

```
<?php
function _YOUR_MODULE_node_resource_access($op, $node_alias)
{
  $path = drupal_get_normal_path($node_alias[0]);
  if ($path !== $node_alias && ctype_digit($nid = str_replace('node/', '', $path))) {
    return _node_resource_access($op, array($nid));
  }
  return services_error(t('Content could not be found.'), 404);
}
```